# How can I set redis key timeout using redigo?

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I'd like to add a timeout to redis key/value pair so that they expire after 10 minutes.

Here is the function

```
func setData(value string) {
    conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379", redis.DialDatabase(1))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not connect: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    conn.Do("SET", "mykey", value)
}
```

I want redigo to do this:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX "mykey" 600 value
```

I'm wondering how can I acheive this in redigo?

I looked at the docs [examples](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#pkg-examples) but could not figure out how to do so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Conn` struct's `Do` method](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Conn) accepts the command name, and a list of arbitrary parameters (typed `...interface{}`).

You can use these parameters to pass any kind of parameter that you would also pass using the Redis CLI:

```
conn.Do("SETEX", "mykey", 600, value)
```

Also, have a look at the ["Executing commands"](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#hdr-Executing_Commands) section from the documentation for more information.